# Understanding arrays and value assignments

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I really do not understand how the value assignments in arrays work. I was going through this piece of code (a method used to reverse the values of an array):

```
 public static int[] reverseArray2(int[] array) 
  {
    int i = 0, j = array.length - 1;
    for (i = 0; i < array.length / 2; i++, j--) 
    {
      int temp = array[i];
      array[i] = array[j];
      array[j] = temp;
    }
    return array;
  }
```

Why is it that in this case the array is now properly swapped? (say for an array composed of the elements {1,2,3,4,5}, and we want to swap it). In which way does the line `array[i] = array[j]` help accomplish this? And as well, how can I know the values assigned to the array are? (or as well, in which way they are overwritten). I tried to use another method, but I got {5,4,3,4,5} as an output.

Comment: Please post you other method.
In `reverseArray2()` you are swapping the first with last, the second with the last but one and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Basically in that loop the index i starts from 0 and increments by 1 per iteration, while j starts from the last array element and decrements by 1 per iteration.

The `i < length / 2` condition ensures i only go as far as middle of the array (this is integer divison so odd numbers don't matter (eg: 5/2 == 2))

`int temp = array[i];` saves the value of array at index i in a temporary variable, and `array[i] = array[j]` overwrites the value at i with the value at j. Finally `array[j] = temp` recover the temporary variable and place it at j.

Comment: Alright, I think I finally understood how it works. I thought that we traversed through the ENTIRE array, but we are only doing it until half (the middle value pretty much is left untouched). 

However, when having those occasions in which the values of the array are affected mostly pertain when you assign an array equality and then you change the values in one array (thus affecting the other one)?

Comment: `x = y` is not equality, but assignment. It's saying 'copy value of y into x'. Equality is `x == y`

Answer (score 0):

Swapping two values in memory always requires a third (`temp` in this case). You set the current value of one of the cells aside (temp = ...), then overwrite what was stored in that cell before (a[i] = a[j]), and finally place the original cell value into its new spot (a[j] = a[i]).

The for loop here just goes to the half-way point of the array, incrementing one counter from 0 and decrementing another from `array.length-1`

Answer (score 0):

Lets have an example

```
array={1,2,3,4,5}
```

now at first when we enter the loop 
we have

```
i=0,J=4
```

now, we have three lines

1.) `temp =a[i] = a[0] = 1;`
so now one is stored to a different memory location under the variable temp.

similarly,

2.) `a[i] = a[j] =a[4] =5;`

here 5 is assigned to memory location where previously 1 was stored and that location is under `a[0]`. ie now Ist element of array has become 5

now,

3.) `a[j]=temp=1;`

so now last element of array at location `a[4]` becomes equal to 1 which was first element earlier.

At last in the next loop temp will be initialized by second element and used for swapping second and second last element.

Note: I guess now it is also obvious that why we ran the loop to half of actual size of array.

Answer (score 0):

The line `array[i] = array[j]` executes from right-to-left. It means the value of `array[j]` is going to be put into `array[i]`.

This also means that you can not write in the following way:

```
array[i] = array[j]
array[j] = array[i]
```

as it will destroy the value of `array[i]` if you don't save it to other variable, say `temp`.
So first save it to `temp`: `int temp = array[i]`. Then put the value of `array[j]` to `array[i]`: `array[i] = array[j]`. Finally put `array[i]` to `array[j]` by `array[j] = temp`.

If the above concept is clear, then we may simulate the loop in the following way:

Say, the list is {1,2,3,4,5}

- i = 0, then j = 4

  ```
  1 2 3 4 5
  ^       ^
  i       j
  ```

  now the code inside the loop will swap the values and the array will look like:

  ```
  5 2 3 4 1
  ^       ^
  i       j
  ```
- i = 1, then j = 3

  ```
  1 2 3 4 5
    ^   ^
    i   j
  ```

  now the code inside the loop will swap the values and the array will look like:

  ```
  5 4 3 2 1
    ^   ^
    i   j
  ```
- i = 2, `i < array.length / 2` condition fails. so the loop exits.

Now you have the reversed list : `{ 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}`